# найти сумму элементов, расположенных между первым четным элементом и последним нечетным элементом массива

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, возникла такая проблема, вывел я массив, заполнил случайными числами ,но не могу понять как сделать своё задание

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10
#define A -50
#define B 50

void Init(int *a, int n)
{
int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
a[i] = A + rand() % (B -A + 1); 
}
void Print(int *a, int n)
{
int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
printf("%d ", a[i]);
putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: А что делать, если в массиве нет либо четных, либо нечетных элементов?

Comment: @gbg то, что вопрос - учебное задание - не может являться причиной закрытия. Справа в блоке важного на мете висит ссылка на обсуждение с решением. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/ Пожалуйста, перестаньте нарушать правила и закрывать вопросы, являющиеся онтопиком.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм решения задачи.

1. Просматривая массив с начала, ищем чётный элемент. Если нашли, сохраняем его индекс (`index1`). Если чётных нет, положим `index1=-1`.
2. Просматривая массив с конца, ищем нечётный элемент. Если нашли, сохраняем его индекс (`index2`). Если нечётных нет, положим `index2=-1`.
3. Если либо `index1<0`, либо `index2<0`, то считать нечего. В этом случае можно вернуть ноль. Если `index1>index2`, то первый чётный расположен правее последнего нечётного, интервал пустой и опять возвращаем ноль. В остальных случаях суммируем элементы в интервале индексов `[index1+1, index2-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете найти первый четный элемент и последний нечетный элементы в массиве с помощью одной функции.

Для этого следует определить структуру, которая будет хранить два значения: индекс первого четного элемента и индекс последнего нечетного элемента.

В случае, если либо четный элемент, либо нечетный элемент не найден в массиве, выдавать сообщение, что требуемый интервал элементов отсутствует или пустой.

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает данный подход

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct pair
{
    size_t first;
    size_t second;
};

struct pair find_odd_even( int *a, size_t n )
{
    struct pair p = { n, n };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] % 2 == 0 && p.first == n ) p.first = i;
        else p.second = i;
    }

    return p;
}

long long int sum( int *a, struct pair interval )
{
    long long int s = 0;

    if ( interval.first != interval.second )
    {        
        while ( ++interval.first != interval.second ) s += a[interval.first];
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    struct pair p = find_odd_even( a, N );

    if ( p.first == N || p.second == N )
    {
        puts( "There is no valid interval" );
    }
    else
    {        
        if ( p.second < p.first )
        {
            size_t tmp = p.first;
            p.first = p.second;
            p.second = tmp;
        }

        printf( "Sum is equal to %lld\n", sum( a, p ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```